# Magento 500 Errors, Slowness

Tags: php, apache, magento, e-commerce

We're running a magento web store on Knownhost (VPS).

Most of the time the site works fine. Occasionally (every few hours?) the site will get very slow and unresponsive, and will throw '500 Internal Server Errors'. There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in the webserver or Magento system/exception logs.

Also, it seems that we're seeing high CPU usage on this account.

I have increased the memory limit to 512MB, and tried everything else I could find. No dice.

We have a managed VPS, so we can change pretty much everything. We had our hosted provider install ImageMagick after reading a suggestion online - didn't help.

Any ideas?

(website is available at myerstownsheds.com if anyone would like a look)

Comment: That's a bad way to try and solve your problems. What do the errors say?

Comment: It's a generic 500 error: "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." No details at all, and it appears after attempting to load the site for around 30 seconds.

Comment: I did some searching. What might work is removing (backup first) `local.xml` to reset any misfunctioning settings in Magneto. Second I found that it might be a fault in your `.htaccess`. It's also that the error's details are hidden behind the 500-code to prevent private data from leaking. I'm not sure how you can configure it so that it will show the exact cause of the error. I'll try to look some more. Also try to fix the JavaScript bugs on your website (check with a Dev Tool).

Comment: `local.xml` is inside `app/etc/local`. I also read it can be permission-problems on the fileserver (www/htdocs folder). Maybe php doesn't have the correct rights on each folder, making certain actions involving writing to the disc, and thus making them time-out (probably) in a looped fashion.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the local.xml, and went through the setup steps. I got a "PHP Extensions "0" must be loaded."

Comment: Did you do a manual compile of PHP (or package install with Magento?). Also I'm curious on what OS you are. Can mean a lot. The most problems I find online are that the permissions are off. The change of permissions seem to be most common when upgrading Magento or installing modules. Try to use 644 for files and 755 for folders.

Comment: We didn't do a manual compile. We're using CloudLinux (cent based?). I'll look into the permissions thing, not exactly sure how to get them all updated short of doing it by hand...

Comment: I fixed my "PHP Extensions "0" must be loaded." issue while configuring magento, using a simple config.xml edit detailed here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/284882/

Comment: Permissions will probably be the best chance to fix your problem. Check if your PHP "user" (process) has the correct right  to all the files and folders (subs too). Or just wait it out and see by using the clean `local.xml` :) Don't forget to set the memory limit back too. That's very bad to do when using PHP as a web-server language. Also try to use XDebug (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xdebug). It's a very good tool to get the most out of your code debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions posted by allendar:

1. Backup and delete app/etc/local/local.xml
2. Go to site in browser, and follow the configuration process

So far, everything seems to be working fine! It's a little hard to say this soon since the issue was so intermittent, but our site has remained responsive for nearly two hours.

I'm going to mark this as Answered in a couple days. I'll look into getting a better hosting plan.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; You have an under resourced server. Any code or configuration steps you take to reduce load are only going to postpone the inevitable.

It's impossible to provide a concrete answer to your question with the information given.  If you could look at your server logs and see the full error message being generated it would be a big help.  "Server logs" probably mean "Apache Logs" in this situation, since the error text you provided is a standard Apache/PHP error, and not a Magento error.

All that said, the most likely culprit is a PHP out of memory error. Magento's performance profile is different than most LAMP stack applications, and most generic VPS hosts are unable/unwilling to make the tweaks needed to run it.  If you want to solve this problem long term you need a web host that specializes in Magento. I recommend [Nexcess](https://affiliates.nexcess.net/idevaffiliate.php?id=1626) (affiliate link) these days, but [Magento has a list of recommended hosting partners](http://www.magentocommerce.com/partners/hosting), and the [Magento Speed Test](http://www.magespeedtest.com/) site offers a nice breakdown of the top Magento hosts.

Take a look at your host's plans

[image]

The highest level plan tops out at 4GB of RAM (4096 MB).

Take a look at the starting Nexcess plans

[image]

The entry level plan provides 16GB.  Four times as much RAM as your current host. Magento is a RAM hungry application.  Your current host isn't equipped to handle Magento.  Any code or configuration steps you take to reduce load are only going to postpone the inevitable.